# How to Center Images of Different Sizes in the Middle of a div

Tags: html, css

I have various images on a horizontal line. Some images are different sizes, so I want all the images to be centered relative to the div they are contained in, so it looks better. I am hoping to achieve this without the way it is currently set up which is to add a top margin.

Is there a way to automatically do this in css so that if the images change they will still become centered relative to the containing div?

https://jsfiddle.net/0aqavqtL/

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center; margin: 30px 0; width: 100%;">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="margin: 15px 0; text-align: center; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="margin: 15px 0; text-align: center; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="margin: 15px 0; text-align: center; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ef/Dots_video_game_cover.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="margin: 15px 0; text-align: center; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `display: flex` on the parent with `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` will horizontally and vertically center the children in the row.

And if you want the row to wrap to the next line when there isn't enough room for the cols to display side-by-side, apply `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.row.centered`

```css
.row.centered {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row centered"   >
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="">
    <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="">
    <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="">
    <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ef/Dots_video_game_cover.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="">
    <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what specifications I would add to allow this alignment to move over to Mozilla & Safari? I noticed it wasn't working there.

Comment: @penmas should work fine in the latest versions. I just checked in FF & safari and looks like expected. if you're on older versions, you may need to use the browser prefix. I believe it's just `display: -webkit-flex`, `-webkit-align-items: center` and `-webkit-justify-content: center` (and replace `webkit` with `moz` for ff)

Comment: the [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) utility will do it for you, too

Comment: Thanks! @Michael Coker, I actually ended up doing just that, and it worked well! For some reason I had to remove the div class="row" specification for it to work on Safari. Oddly, it began wrapping the preceding text on IE when I removed "row", but it worked fine after adding the prefix's. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox, like this:

```css
.container {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-color: grey;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
flex-basis: 400px;
flex-grow: 1;
margin: 10px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;

}

.item1 {
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="item item1"></div>
<div class="item item2"></div>
<div class="item item13"></div>
</div>
```

You can see that you have a container, with a `display` property of `flex`, and three flex items with different heights.

By setting the container's `align-items` property (which affects the vertical align), to `center`, you'll center all of the flex items, whatever their height is.

This is a very "flexible" design, since it doesn't depend on the size or number of elements.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This looks great, but how do you recommend configuring for mobile views?

Comment: @penmas I updated my code to demonstrate how you can do this.
As you can see, I changed the width property of the flex items for the flex-basis property, which sets the initial width of the element. I set that property to 400px.
Then I added a flex-grow property of 1 to each flexible item, which means they will all grow equally to fill any remaining width in the container.
Finally, I set the flex-wrap property of the container to wrap. This means that if there's not enough space for the items to take up their asigned width, they will wrap to the next line

Comment: @penmas Changing that code snippet will allow you to asign initial widths for the items to take up if there's enough space, and tell them to wrap to the next line if there isn't.
This makes a good responsive design

Comment: @penmas Does this suit your needs?